# Draw route from lat/lng list in SAPUI5

Tags: google-maps, sapui5

I´m using the framework openui5-googlemaps for using google maps in a sapui5 application.

I have an array of lat/lng positions. I want to draw a line from position to position in this array.

I found an example with directions:

```
<gmaps:directions>
        <gmaps:Directions startAddress="{mapModel>/start}" endAddress="mapModel>/end}" unitSystem="1" waypoints="{mapModel>/stops}">
            <gmaps:waypoints>
                <gmaps:Waypoint location="{mapModel>/name}"></gmaps:Waypoint>
            </gmaps:waypoints>
        </gmaps:Directions>
    </gmaps:directions>
```

The problem on this solution is, that I don´t want a marker on each position. 
(My positions have a distance of a few metres.)
Further this solution draws the lines based on the streets. I need a solution regardless of streets.

Comment: sounds like you want to use the [Polyline class](https://github.com/jasper07/openui5-googlemaps/blob/master/src/Polyline.js) instead of the Directions one

Comment: Do you have an example for usage?
I have my problems to get it run in the right way.

Comment: no, and they don't bother giving an example in their samples. I'd say hit up [John Patterson](https://github.com/jasper07) with a request to update the samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see example using Polylines see [Sample App2](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/samples/app2/)

Let me know if you want an standalone example by adding an issue to the repo

[UPDATE]

here is a [sample app using polylines](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/samples/PolylineSample.html)

```
<openui5.googlemaps:Map id="map1" lat="{/beaches/1/lat}" lng="{/beaches/1/lng}" > 
    <openui5.googlemaps:polylines>
        <openui5.googlemaps:Polyline path="{/beaches}" />
    </openui5.googlemaps:polylines>   
</openui5.googlemaps:Map>
```

running looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´m not sure because I´m really new in this topic but you only set markers on this example. I need no markers. Instead of them I only need a drawed linear distance between lat/lng coordinates.

Comment: Is there a opportunity to use the map with satellite imagery? (Not with the road map)